# Replace NA values with values with corresponding from other same

Tags: python, pandas

How can I replace NA values in df1

`df1`:

```
ID col1 col2 col3 col4
A   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
B   0     0   1    2
C   NaN   NaN NaN   NaN
```

With the values from the other dataframe that are corresponding to those NaN values (so other values do not go over)

`df2`:

```
ID col1 col2 col3 col4
A   1     2   1   11
B   2     2   4    8
C   0     0  NaN   NaN
```

So result is

```
ID col1 col2 col3 col4
A   1     2   1    11
B   0     0   1    2
C   0     0 NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Did you try `df1.fillna(df2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use if `ID` are index in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = df1.fillna(df2)
```

Or:

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

---

```
print (df)
    col1  col2  col3  col4
ID                        
A    1.0   2.0   1.0  11.0
B    0.0   0.0   1.0   2.0
C    0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN
```

If `ID` are columns:

```
df = df1.set_index('ID').fillna(df2.set_index('ID'))
#alternative
#df = df1.set_index('ID').combine_first(df2.set_index('ID'))
```

Comment: Even though the columns are the same in both dataframes, i checked df1.columns and df2.columns and one is normal index and one is multiindex. Any idea how to quickly convert to standard index?

Comment: @AlexT - Can you change data samples? Because it depends of MultiIndex

Comment: `MultiIndex([(     'ID',),
            ('2017-01',),
            ('2017-02',),
            ('2017-03',),
            ('2017-04',),
            ('2017-05',)],)` This is the multinindex I get ine one dataframe even though it looks the same as the other (which is normal index)

Comment: The other one is: `Index(['ID', '2017-01', '2017-02', '2017-03', '2017-04', '2017-05'])`

Comment: @AlexT - What is code for create `df1` with `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: Yeah I figured out the problem it was because i renamed columns using double brackets `[[...column names]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

(rows, columns) = df1.shape
for i in range(rows):
 for j in range(columns):
  if df1.iloc[i,j] == np.NaN:
   df1.iloc[i,j] = df2.iloc[i,j]
```

If all df1 missing values have a corresponding value in df2, that should work.

This solution also takes in count that the NaN values are expressed correctly in df1 as np.NaN, so if they are in string format or another one it will raise an exception.